# scopeButtonTitles in UISearchController with UINavigation iOS 11

Tags: ios, iphone, ios11, uisearchcontroller

scopebuttontitles layout display incorrect. Please help me check it.

When I tap in textbox of uisearchbar. ScopeButtonTitles display correct,
But when I rotate iphone screen to portrait then ScopeButtonTitles display incorrect as image

[image]

I rotate iphone screen to landscape again ScopeButtonTitles display incorrect as image

[image]

Comment: Have the same issue. This is 100% certain a bug in iOS 11, Apple really dropped the ball on this one. http://www.openradar.me/34504787